# Fixed points of a homogeneous polynomial

Tags: polynomials, probability-distributions, systems-of-equations, roots, fixed-points

Consider a homogeneous polynomial $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by

$$ f(x) = \sum_{|\alpha| = k} b_{\alpha} x^\alpha = \sum_{\alpha_1+\ldots+\alpha_n = k} b_{\alpha} \prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{\alpha_j} $$

where $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n$ is a [multi-index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation#Definition_and_basic_properties) and $b_{\alpha} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I am studying the fixed points of $f$ that lie on the [standard simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#The_standard_simplex) in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so $x$ is a categorical distribution on $n$ possible outcomes.

Do these fixed points $x = f(x)$ have a closed-form expression? Is there a unique fixed point? Can any properties of fixed points be determined, such as their entropy?

Comment: why should the fixed points be related to the entropy

Comment: @cactus314 I'm just trying to see if any properties of the fixed points can be determined, if no closed-form solution exists.